# Accessing text within <li> tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a list of `<li>` items that are dragged using jQuerys drag/drop. I'd like to grab the text within the `<li>` tag just when the item is dropped, append the text to a global variable so that selected values can be submitted to a servlet.

To handle the functionality when the item is dropped I can use below jQuery callback :

```
stop: function(event, ui) { 
    //update variable here
}
```

How can I grab the text value within the `<li>` tag and append it to a global variable ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ui.draggable.text()` in the `drop` event of droppable.

```
drop: function(event, ui) { 
    myVar += ui.draggable.text();
}
```

Or `ui.helper.text()` in the `stop` event of draggable.

```
stop: function(event, ui) { 
    myVar += ui.helper.text();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the text from the `ui.helper` representing the dragged object:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
  stop: function( event, ui ){
    globalVar =  ui.helper.text(); 
  }
});
```

`ui.helper` is also available to `droppable` as well.